# Tag system, checking if tag already exist or no

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tags

I'm working on a tag system with PhP and MySQL (InnoDB).
In my database I have 2 table :

`contentTable` :

`content` | `tagsID`

"content1" | "1, 3"

"content2" | "2, 3"

`tags` :

`tagID` (PrimaryKey) | `tag`

1 | "politics"

2 | "interview"

3 | "economy"

Each content have a set of tag listed in tagsID by each tagID.

I'm trying to make insert.php to add new content. Before adding a content, each tag is checked to make sure it exist :

- if it doesn't, it adds it to tags table and get his primary key (`tagID`)
- if it already exist, it gets his `tagID`.

tagsID[] is at each iteration filled with is the ID of each tag and then concatenated ('$tagID1 . ', ' . $tagID2 etc..') to be stored in `tagsID` of `contentTable`.

The code I made is I believe : inefficient, badly designed, unproductive.

```php
        $tags = $_POST['tags'];
        $tags = explode(", ", $tags);

        foreach ($tags as $i => $tag ) {
            $req = $bdd-> prepare("SELECT tagID FROM tags WHERE tag = ?");
            $req->execute(array($tag));

            while ($tagID = $req->fetch())
            {
                if (empty($tagID['tagID'])) {
                    // create the tag (INSERT VALUES("", $tag))
                    // get the ID of the new tag
                    // add it to $tagsID[]
                    echo $tag . ' tag added, ID : ' . $newTagID . '<br>';
                } else {
                    // $tagID['tagID'] is added to $tagsID[]
                }
            }
            // JOIN string of $tagsID array in this format tagsID[0] . ", " . tagsID[1] . ", " etc...
            INSERT VALUES ($content, $tagsID[])
        }
```

How would you approach this ?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: It's MySQL from Xampp using InnoDB engine
Not sure if i answered your question

Comment: I would use MySQL's UPDATE functionality to check if the tag already exists. If the tag exists, update it, otherwise use INSERT to insert a new tag.

Comment: I tried to make it more understandable.